# Want null able but not of the same type

Tags: c#, winforms

First of many thanks for taking time on this post I have a problem I am pasting in values from excel spreed sheet now the column will be a mixture of blanks and intergers. If the line is blank we want to deleted and if its zero or a number leave as is.

Is there a neater way of handling this.

```
double _oldNewSpsPrice = Convert.ToDouble(dgUpdatesPrices.Rows[e.RowIndex]
.Cells["NSPSPRICE"].Value);
```

Cause as you no if you enter ""  this line will fall over with a not valid statment

It will complain that input string is not in correct format now I no I could make it nullable but I do not want to turn the blank string into a zero but rather leave it as is.

Do I really have to add if statements around everywhere or is there a neater way of handling this.

For example

[image]

Many thanks for assistance.

**Edit 2**
Also when I do this it gives me an error when I try to check for blank.

```
if(dgUpdatesPrices.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["NSPSPRICE"].Value.ToString()!="")
```

Comment: use TryParse with an out parameter. then it will not give any exception. You  can then check if the value of the paramerter is null or not. see this: https://www.dotnetperls.com/parse

Comment: @alaa_sayegh is their anyway of handling this in the class would hate to change it everywhere now

Comment: In dgUpdatesPrices.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["NSPSPRICE"].Value, is value an object or string?  If it is an object, you would get an error doing ToString on it if it was null.

Comment: it can either be a blank which would be treated as "" or else a 0 or a value decimal thanks for asking

Comment: @david39ni I referring to the type of Value.  Is it an object or string?  I believe it is a object.  If so, I'll update my example below.

Comment: @david39ni, sorry i was not online yesterday to answer that, but i see that you got a solution, great :)!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd suggest some type of C# Extension if it is repetitive code that you are trying to avoid.  Something list this:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool ShouldWeDeleteThisExcelLine(this string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
            return true;

        double someValue;
        if (double.TryParse(input, out someValue) == false)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

It would be used like this

```
if (dgUpdatesPrices.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["NSPSPRICE"]
     .Value.ShouldWeDeleteThisExcelLine()) 
{   
   /* delete it */ 
}
```

-----------------------EDIT (add)-----------------------

If value is an OBJECT and NOT a string, use this:

```
public static class MyObjectExtensions
{
   public static bool ShouldWeDeleteThisExcelLine(this object input)
   {
       string stringInput = (string) input;

       if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringInput))
           return true;

        double someValue;
        return double.TryParse(stringInput, out someValue) == false;
   }
}
```

It would be used like this:

```
if   (dgUpdatesPrices.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["NSPSPRICE"]
   .Value?.ShouldWeDeleteThisExcelLine() ?? true) 
{  
    /* note the safe navigation operator  ?. since extension work on instantiated objects */ 
    /* delete it */ 
}
```

An alternative is a helper method

```
public class MyHelpers
{
    public static bool ShouldWeDeleteThisExcelLine(object input)
    {
        string stringInput = (string) input;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringInput))
            return true;

        double someValue;
        return double.TryParse(stringInput, out someValue) == false;
    }
}

if (MyHelpers.ShouldWeDeleteThisExcelLine(
   dgUpdatesPrices.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["NSPSPRICE"].Value))
{      
    /* delete it */ 
}
```

Comment: your reputation should be way more that is a very neat answer sir.but  I would go one further have a column marked for delation or I would have the same issue when it comes to firing it in

Comment: your extnesion says it requires a string value so your usage does not compile

Comment: @david39ni  try the extension for object above and see if that works.  I suspect that value is an object type and not a string type.